# Mono for Android: my ListView grows and my buttons go off the screen

Tags: android, mono

I have some components on one axml:

- a) a first  listView named "Titles"
- b) a second listView named "Data"
- c) a TableLayout with 3 buttons

I'm trying to have

- a) ListView "Titoli" always visible at the top of the screen   (and
  this happens)
- b) ListView "Lista"  always visible immediately under "Titoli" (and
  this happens)
- c) TableLayout tableLayout1 always visible at the bottom of the
  screen

And this is my problem: if the ListView Lista grows with a lot of items, the TableLayout goes off the screen.

Someone can help?
I really don't understand how I can lock the TableLayout at the bottom of the screen and avoid it disappering.

Comment: Put the list inside a scrollable panel?

Answer (score 0):

A ListView can have footer/header view and these views will always be visible on the screen. These views can be added with the corresponding methods addHeaderView/addFooterView.

I don't know your app logic, but I don't think you need 2 listViews (considering there names). Please see APIDemos: ExpandableList or List->ListAdapterCollapseble.

I hope it helps:)

Comment: Yes, it helps, the idea is good, but I'm so new to Mono for Android I don't know how to build a "view" and load in this view the correct .axml i need for the "titles" part of the window. Could you give me some lines of code to do that?